# How to prove across language boundaries about functions written in another language via FFI?

Tags: idris

I know that a proof assistant can prove properties expressed in its own language. However, I find it desirable to call libraries written in other languages when using proof assistants. For example, I'd like to be able to call BLAS for matrix operations without having to re-implement all these in a proof language (e.g. idris2).

My question is then how can one prove some computation that is delegated to another language (e.g. via Foreign Function Interfaces (FFIs)). Does it even work? I guess this must have already happened at some level. Languages like idris using machine integers to replace the unary `Nat`s in computation behind the scene (from what I read). But I am just wondering if this can be done by the general public/user.

For example, idris2 documentation has the following FFI function for adding two integers in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int x, int y) {
    return x+y;
}
```

(small.c)

The FFI is then imported into idris via the following declaration.

```
%foreign "C:add,libsmall"
add : Int -> Int -> Int

main : IO ()
main = printLn (add 70 24)
```

Now, I can prove simple properties such as the commutativity of addition if the function were defined inductively on Nats.

*But how can I prove the same for the FFI version of `add`?*

*More generally, is proving about FFIs possible in proof assistants, and what is the mechanism to prove across the boundaries about a piece of code that the PA doesn't really know?*

Comment: FFI by definition only provides access to the *interface* (that's the letter I). So the implementation will not be exposed, thus cannot be reasoned with other than using postulates (or something like contracts). If it were exposed that's no longer an interface.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you are content with. One possibility is to axiomatize the foreign function you want to call, and its properties. That way, you can certify your code with respect to the hypothetical specification of the foreign function. I don't know about Idris, but this is how [primitive integers/floats/arrays](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/core/primitive.html#primitive-objects) are handled in Coq: there is an opaque type of integers, with a bunch of functions on it, and axiomatized properties of those. These are still considered axioms, but if you realize the types and functions by foreign ones satisfying the axioms, the properties of extraction tell you that all should go well: your code will satisfy its proven properties. It is an important and difficult property of extraction that it stays correct in presence of axioms, as long as these are realized in the extracted code.

As Trebor mentions in their comment, philosophically this is what one should expect of a foreign function interface: the whole point is to call a function your language does not know about. Still, this is somewhat unsatisfying, as you lose quite a bit of guarantees, since you cannot guarantee the foreign function meets its axiomatized specification. The other option would be to call code certified using one of the many program certification platforms out there. But I am not sure exactly how this would work, in the sense that these certification tools work on (deeply embedded) program *code*, in most cases against a particular operational semantics, while certification in the proof assistant directly certifies a *function* (which from the "meta" level is also a program, but the proof assistant does not know that). Thus, you would need to provide a link between the semantics of the program code and the foreign function you want to call, so that you can translate a certified property of the former into one of the latter. This is a very interesting direction for research, as FFI are often a source of subtle bugs, but I do not know of any existing tools that tackle it.